# Spring app connects to in-memory H2 db instead of file based

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jdbc, h2

I am trying to create a local database in disk and connect to it. Basically I want jdbc.h2.file, not jdbc.h2.mem. This is how I set up the application.properties.file

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = none
spring.datasource.url:jdbc:h2:file:~/test
spring.datasource.driverClassName:org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username:sa
spring.datasource.password:
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.h2.console.path=/h2-console
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.flyway.url:jdbc:h2:file:~/test
spring.flyway.user:sa
spring.flyway.password:
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
spring.flyway.locations=filesystem:./src/main/resources/db/migration
```

Spring log looks like this:

```
2022-05-22 13:21:34.094  INFO 46252 --- [           main] com.zhandos.SOLIDBankApp.Main            : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2022-05-22 13:21:34.408  INFO 46252 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2022-05-22 13:21:34.416  INFO 46252 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 5 ms. Found 0 JPA repository interfaces.
2022-05-22 13:21:34.651  INFO 46252 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2022-05-22 13:21:34.655  INFO 46252 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2022-05-22 13:21:34.655  INFO 46252 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/10.0.18]
2022-05-22 13:21:34.706  INFO 46252 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2022-05-22 13:21:34.708  INFO 46252 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 586 ms
2022-05-22 13:21:34.775  INFO 46252 --- [           main] o.f.c.internal.license.VersionPrinter    : Flyway Community Edition 8.5.11 by Redgate
2022-05-22 13:21:34.775  INFO 46252 --- [           main] o.f.c.internal.license.VersionPrinter    : See what's new here: https://flywaydb.org/documentation/learnmore/releaseNotes#8.5.11
2022-05-22 13:21:34.775  INFO 46252 --- [           main] o.f.c.internal.license.VersionPrinter    : 
2022-05-22 13:21:34.780  INFO 46252 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2022-05-22 13:21:34.831  INFO 46252 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Added connection conn0: url=jdbc:h2:mem:d2716439-cb1c-4995-bb7a-1e672e3d7a42 user=SA
2022-05-22 13:21:34.832  INFO 46252 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2022-05-22 13:21:34.838  INFO 46252 --- [           main] o.f.c.i.database.base.BaseDatabaseType   : Database: jdbc:h2:mem:d2716439-cb1c-4995-bb7a-1e672e3d7a42 (H2 2.1)
2022-05-22 13:21:34.869  INFO 46252 --- [           main] o.f.core.internal.command.DbValidate     : Successfully validated 2 migrations (execution time 00:00.007s)
2022-05-22 13:21:34.872  INFO 46252 --- [           main] o.f.c.i.s.JdbcTableSchemaHistory         : Creating Schema History table "PUBLIC"."flyway_schema_history" ...
2022-05-22 13:21:34.895  INFO 46252 --- [           main] o.f.core.internal.command.DbMigrate      : Current version of schema "PUBLIC": << Empty Schema >>
2022-05-22 13:21:34.898  INFO 46252 --- [           main] o.f.core.internal.command.DbMigrate      : Migrating schema "PUBLIC" to version "1.1 - Add transaction table"
2022-05-22 13:21:34.904  INFO 46252 --- [           main] o.f.core.internal.command.DbMigrate      : Migrating schema "PUBLIC" to version "1.2 - Add account table"
2022-05-22 13:21:34.908  INFO 46252 --- [           main] o.f.core.internal.command.DbMigrate      : Successfully applied 2 migrations to schema "PUBLIC", now at version v1.2 (execution time 00:00.015s)
2022-05-22 13:21:34.969  INFO 46252 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2022-05-22 13:21:34.985  INFO 46252 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.6.7.Final
2022-05-22 13:21:35.031  INFO 46252 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.2.Final}
2022-05-22 13:21:35.066  INFO 46252 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
2022-05-22 13:21:35.126  INFO 46252 --- [           main] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
2022-05-22 13:21:35.132  INFO 46252 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2022-05-22 13:21:35.169  WARN 46252 --- [           main] JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
2022-05-22 13:21:35.330  INFO 46252 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2022-05-22 13:21:35.337  INFO 46252 --- [           main] com.zhandos.SOLIDBankApp.Main            : Started Main in 1.434 seconds (JVM running for 1.771)
```

However, I do not want the database to be in-memory. I tried all the suggestions to similar questions over the web, tried different combinations in application.properties but the efforts were futile. It seems like the in-memory (mem) database is set as default and cannot be changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was actually very silly mistake from me, the problem was resolved when the `:` was replaced with `=`

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = none
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:file:~/test
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=
spring.h2.console.path=/h2-console
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.flyway.url=jdbc:h2:file:~/test
spring.flyway.user=sa
spring.flyway.password=
```

Answer (score 0):

use it this way

```
spring.datasource.url:jdbc:h2:/home/ubuntu/test
```

you need to pass the absolute path to the file

Comment: Tried that too, unfortunately, no improvements

Comment: @yernazarov could you please share the code after using the absolute path?